# В чем отличие между readLine() и readln() в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Пытался написать консольный калькулятор и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Если в переменную присваивать значение через `readLine()`, то в последующем ее нельзя преобразовать с помощью функции `toInt()`. А если использовать функцию `readln()`, то компилятор во время преобразования не ругается.

В чем разница?

Comment: `readLine()` будет в будущем обьявлен deprecated. Новый код стоит писать используя `readln()` или `readlnOrNull()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно перейти в реализацию метода `readln()` и сразу все станет ясно:

```kotlin
public actual fun readln(): String =
    readLine() ?: throw ReadAfterEOFException("EOF has already been reached")
```

Единственное отличие `readln()` от `readLine()` это то, что первый метод выбросит исключение, когда будет достигнут конец файла, а второй метод молчаливо вернет `null`.

Если для вашей задачи подохдит `readLine()`, то вместо него лучше использовать более говорящий эквивалент `readlnOrNull()`. В будущих релизах `readLine()` будет помечен как [устаревший](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew16.html#new-readline-functions).

---

Так как в вашей программе вы вводите данные из консоли, то [EOF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF), конец файла, можно сымитировать, нажав <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> для Windows). Посмотрите, как поведет ваша программа:

- Если вы используете `readln()`, то получите ошибку `EOF has already been reached` и программа завершится, если вы не обработаете это исключение.
- Если же вы используете `readLine()` или `readlnOrNull()`, то вы сами можете проверить результат на `null` и решить что делать в таком случае. Завершить программу с ошибкой или что-то другое:

  ```kotlin
  val number = readLine()?.toInt()
  if (number == null) {
      // достигли конца файла
  }
  ```

Comment: О `readLine()` уже стоит забыть и использовать `readlnOrNull()` как прямой заменитель.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, точно, хотя `readLine()` еще не помечен как deprecated в Kotlin 1.7.10, [тут написано](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew16.html#new-readline-functions), что в будущих релизах от него планируется отказаться в пользу `readln()` и `readlnOrNull()`.

Answer (score 1):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew16.html#new-readline-functions
Если вкратце, то readln() возвращает not null тип String, а если строку не удается прочитать бросает `RuntimeException`. В свою очередь readline() возвращает String?, которая может быть null. Более новой альтернативой к последнему является добавленная в 1.6.0 readlnOrNull().

Comment: Разверните ответ, вы же верную ссылку привели.

Comment: Да, ссылка то, что надо, но смущает формулировка "вроде не может быть null", конечно не может быть null, это же видно по возвращаемому значению.